# Оператор "::" и глобальное пространство имен в С++

Tags: c++

```
int val = 0; // глобальная переменная
void func()
{
    int val = 1;
    необходимо вывести глобальную val
    cout << val << endl; // можно ли использовать "::"?
}
```

Есть ли идентификатор у глобального пространства имен, и можно ли использовать его с "::"?

Comment: Нашлось _AGLOBAL, работает, но возможно есть еще варианты?

cout << _AGLOBAL::val << endl;

Comment: Есть - пустое имя. Так и используете: `::val`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

именное пространство :

```
namespace Your {
int val = 0; // глобальная переменная
}
void func()
{
    int val = 1;
    //необходимо вывести глобальную val
    cout << Your::val << endl; // можно ли использовать "::"?
}
```

или глобальное пространство :

```
int val = 0; // глобальная переменная
void func()
{
    int val = 1;
    //необходимо вывести глобальную val
    cout << ::val << endl; // можно ли использовать "::"?
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) небольшая опечатка в первой строке (правильно namespace, я полагаю)

Comment: Безымянное и глобальное ПИ — это разные вещи. Это не существенно в примере, но в нём нет безымянного ПИ.